# Exoplayer: Loop creates OutOfMemoryError when playing video from local file

Tags: android, firebase, out-of-memory, exoplayer2.x

When I try to play a video from a local file (I assume it's `.mp4`) in the `ExoPlayer 2.10.6`, I get a `OutOfMemoryError`. I download the video from a `firebase` DB and then load it with `Exoplayer`. The `fragment` with the `Exoplayer` exists twice, but I release the `Exoplayer` in `onPause`.

Here where I initialise the `Exoplayer`, `displayVideo` is called in `onResume` and later while the `fragment` is running:

```
private void displayVideo() {       
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext());      
    mMediaPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(), com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), getContext().getString(R.string.app_name)));
    MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.fromFile(new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), profilePicVideoName)));
    exoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    exoPlayer.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
    mMediaPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
}
```

Here where I release the `Exoplayer`:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (exoPlayer != null) {
        exoPlayer.release();
        exoPlayer = null;
    }
    mMediaPlayerView.setPlayer(null);
}
```

The video-file in `firebase` is < 1MB.

**Edit:**

`new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), Helper.profilePicVideoName).length()` = 629440

And the **error-message** is pretty useless:

```
E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 65548 byte allocation with 10220 free bytes and 9KB until OOM"
E/LoadTask: OutOfMemory error loading stream
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 65548 byte allocation with 19092 free bytes and 18KB until OOM
```

**Edit 2:**

Ok, without the loop of the video, no `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown. It doesn't matter, if I loop the video with `setRepeatMode`, with a `LoopingMediaSource` or by adding a Listener that calls `exoPlayer.prepare`.

The only thing that stops the `OutOfMemoryError` is adding a listener, and with every loop to release everything with `releaseMediaPlayer()` and then re-instantiating `Exoplayer`, `Mediasource` and so on. But then there is a black frame between every loop and the CPU is used way more than necessary. The memory consumption drops DRASTICALLY from 180 MB, where `OutOfMemory` occurs to < 100 MB.

Why can't I loop the regular way? What can I do to get rid of the black frame or to optimize CPU usage?

Comment: I have same issue! When video is large >500 MB and duration of that video only 40-50 sec. Because of One Plus mobile high resolution camera!

Comment: I suspect I might be having the same issue. Have you tried submitting an issue on the ExoPlayer Github issues page? https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues

Comment: @Jamie : I did:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7480
The result is the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is the reason why it created an OutOfMemoryError:

The Exoplayer has the great idea to buffer a certain length of the video if in loop-modus. If this buffer length in seconds is longer than the video length, the exoplayer just buffers the video multiple times, using a lot of memory.
If the exoplayer wants to buffer 10sec and the vidoe is 3sec long, the exoplayer will buffer the complete video > 3 times.

There is a way to modify settings of the exoplayer, so you can set how many seconds should be buffered. I decreased the seconds and stopped having OOME.

Comment: Could you add code details how to `decreased the seconds` as you said, to avoid `OOME` error?

Comment: Yes please! I have the same question!

Comment: I have the same plz add code

Comment: The OP is lying about resolving it. Look at this line on this GitHub issue. OP says: "I tweaked a few parameter, that helped, I can't post whcih ones for now, but I think this issue can be closed". The GitHub issue was created by OP https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7480`